# Why is my entity object not inserting data?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data

Here's is my situation.. I'm new in Objective-C and I'm trying to make my first core data sample but I've been stuck in this too many hours. The code should insert an attribute called "id" into my Points entity. Here is a piece of my code I hope u guys can help to find out what I'm missing or making wrong.

location.m

```
-(IBAction)insert_click:(id)sender{                
    NSNumber* x = [NSNumber numberWithInt: 10]; 
    Msa_v3AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
    Points *p =(Points *) [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Points" inManagedObjectContext:context];  
    [p setId:x];    

    NSError *error;     
    if(![managedObjectContext save:&error]){        
        //handle error      
    } 
}
```

**the location class is a NSObject class

Points.h

```
@interface Points :  NSManagedObject  
{
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * id;

@end
```

Point.m

```
@implementation Points 

@dynamic id;

@end
```

The code is compiled ok and is sending no error or warning messages but the insert is still not working.. any clues?

Comment: How are you coming to the conclusion that the insert is not working? You must be fetching the entities. Can you show the code that does the fetch?

Comment: You can also examine your database with an SQLite viewer application, to make sure whether your data is inserted or not.

Comment: thanks for your comments, the code we acctualy inserting the data, the problem was in my fetching method.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got the answer to this issue and i figured out my app was actually inserting data, but my fetching method was wrong, i was initializing my entity object like

```
    Points *p =(Points *) [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Points" inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

instead of

```
    Points *p =(Points *) [NSEntityDescription EntityForName:@"Points" inManagedObjectContext:context];
```